# Javascript destructuring: Assigning defaults with dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-apollo

I am working with `apollo`'s `useQuery` hook and I am looking for a more concise way to write the following statement when `data` is `undefined` (or if this is even achievable).

```js
// hook example
// const {data: {foo=[]}, loading} = useQuery(Q);
const {data:{foo}, loading} = {data: {foo: [1, 2, 3, 4]}, loading: false};
console.log(foo, loading);
```

when data is `undefined`:

```js
// hook example
// const {data:{}, loading} = useQuery(Q);
// const {foo} = data;
const {data={}, loading} = {data: undefined, loading: true};
const {foo=[]} = data;
console.log(foo, loading);
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. Just combine the default assignments from the second snippet. This will assign `data` to an empty object literal if it is undefined. If `data` doesn't have a `foo` property, it will assign an empty array literal to `foo`

```js
const { data: { foo = [] } = {}, loading} = { data: undefined, loading: true };
console.log(foo, loading);
```

Comment: You sir, deserve a cookie! Ahh, this has been driving me crazy for the past 30 mins, was convinced you couldn't assign and go deep at the same time!